# How can I set a zero-value instead of null in LINQ Select Sum

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Im trying to do a query with LINQ to my EF Code First database to retrieve sales for the whole year and return a new DTO object that consists of the Month-number and the total sum of sales that month.

My query works fine, but the months that contains no sales returns null instead of "0", which creates problems in my View.

I have tried the null coalescing `??` but get a compile error that its not valid for a `decimal`. I've also tried the `DefaultIfEmpty` but this does not seem to work together with the .Sum-method.

Any suggestions?

Model:

```
public class YearlySalesDto
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSales { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IEnumerable<YearlySalesDto> Index()
{
    var result = from r in db.Orders
                 group r by r.OrderDate.Month into g
                 select new YearlySalesDto { Month = g.Key.ToString() ?? "", TotalSales = g.Sum(p => p.OrderItems.Select(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice).Sum()) };

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Result from this query, since I only have sales in the DB from months 3 and 4.

```
[
  {
    "Month": "3",
    "TotalSales": 158
  },
  {
    "Month": "4",
    "TotalSales": 373
  }
]
```

Comment: Please show `YearlySalesDto`

Comment: if `g.Key` is null then `g.Key.ToString() ` is an exception, you need to provide complete details including models

Comment: Also `??` is not valid for a `decimal` as it needs to be a nullable type `decimal?`

Comment: your select has nothing to do with this problem, you could get rid of it and still see the issue, `GroupBy` does not return values where `g.Count == 0`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain OP said "months that contains no sales returns null" and not that they are not part of the result set (as you are suggesting). He might have stated it wrong though.

Comment: I've added the Model and the method-call. Is there any way to return 0 if g.count = 0 ?

Comment: Try this, count check for **g.Count**,
TotalSales = `g.Count() > 0 ?g.Sum(p => p.OrderItems.Select(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice).Sum()) : 0`

Comment: On what exactly did you get that error of not a valid decimal?

Comment: @granit except that the OP also said *"I have tried the null coalescing ?? but get a compile error that its not valid for a decimal"*, Month can't be null if it is a decimal.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Just updated - month is a string :(

Comment: @GiladGreen we need to see the type of `OrderDate.Month`, that is where the decimal is.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Then I'm missing something.. on what then did the compilation error occur with the decimal (If Month is a string and not a decimal)?

Comment: @GiladGreen if `r.OrderDate.Month` is a `decimal` doing `g.Key ?? ""` on it will throw the error the OP saw. He showed us the class for `YearlySalesDto` but we need to see the classes for `Orders` and `OrderDate` too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select has nothing to do with this problem, you could get rid of it and still see the issue, `GroupBy` does not return values where `g.Count == 0`, what you need to do is add placeholder entries for the months with no rows in `db.Orders` with 0 as a total and merge that in with your results.

```
var result = from r in db.Orders
             group r by r.OrderDate.Month
             into g
             select new YearlySalesDto { 
                Month = g.Key.ToString(), // The  ?? "" is unnecessary. 
                TotalSales = g.Sum(p => p.OrderItems.Select(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice).Sum()) 
            };

var fixedResult = result.AsEnumerable()
                        .Union(Enumerable.Range(1,12)
                                         .Select(x=>new YearlySalesDto { Month = x.ToString(), TotalSales = 0 })
                               , new MonthComparer());


//Elsewhere
class MonthComparer : IEqualityComparer<YearlySalesDto>
{
    public bool Equals(YearlySalesDto x, YearlySalesDto y)
    {
        return x.Month == y.Month;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(YearlySalesDto x)
    {
        return x.Month.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are crazy...you came up with that pretty fast. +1

Comment: This works great. Thanks a lot for a good explanation and a very nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

The compilation error you received is explained by @Scott in the comment above.

As for having a zero value for months what are not in the database left join the results with a collection of months and in case of `null` place `0`:

```
var result = from m in Enumerable.Range(1,12)
             join g in db.Orders.GroupBy(r => r.OrderDate.Month) on m equals g.Key into joint
             from g in joint.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new YearlySalesDto { 
                 Month = m.ToString(),
                 TotalSales = g == null ? 0 :  g.Sum(p => p.OrderItems.SelectMany(x => x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice))
             };
```

Comment: I believe `"0"` would be more appropriate for OP

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - True and I actually think it is probably because `Month` is a decimal in `YearlySalesDto`. Asked to see definition

Comment: `OrderDate.Month` is a string and `m` is an integer, how shall they be compared using `Equals`. In Scott's answer he has converted the month to string explicitly, which is what you shall also do `m.ToString()`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj what is the problem with comparing two numeric types?

Comment: In the model updated by OP Month is a string, so it's numeric to string comparison

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - I know in the model it is a string :) but the comparing is in the left join while they are both numeric.

Comment: @GiladGreen Alright so `Orders` table contain `Month` as number, I am not too clear regarding it from OP's description, but fairly valid assumption to make a comparison in that case, since `string` is in resultant `DTO`